# Solr phrase search: How can I dynamically increase boost of a particular word?

Tags: search, solr, relevance, phrase

If I search with the phrase "anti corrosion methods"(without quotes), I get "anti-bacterial" documents higher in the results order. I am using text_general fieldType. What I would rather expect is documents having corrosion or anti-corrosion.

How can I decrease the importance of "anti" & "methods" and increase the importance of "corrosion" while searching the phrase. Yeah, I can use anti^0.01 corrosion^10 methods^0.01, but how to do it for dynamic queries?

**Edit:** Probably the individual word boosting might not be a practical solution. I am looking for some approach to handle these kind of scenario.

Comment: you want to have a solution for every query, that should understand which words show be downboosted and which - upboosted?

Comment: @Mysterion: I want to know how to solve these kind of scenarios. Not necessarily the way I mentioned. In the given example, I want to show documents which are specific to corrosion. Because of term frequency, in my case, the documents having "anti" are getting higher score.